How to get collision position for one time not every frame?
I want it to give me the position once when I get the TargetPos.position from the collision
But when I get position of TargetPos get the position in every frame so when I change the position of the object, TargetPos also changes.
The interesting thing is that when I disable collider of the gameObject, I still get the updated position every frame
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        TargetPos = collision.gameObject.transform;
        attackDirection = TargetPos.position - transform.position;
        targetPosTemp = attackDirection + transform.position;
    }
}  

I get TargetPos and targetPosTemp in a ridiculous way...

Are you saying that when you disable the collider, you're still getting OnTriggerEnter2D callbacks? Or are you saying that you are getting the callback on every frame but you only want it on the initial collision?

no i don't getting OnTriggerEnter2D callback but i still get collision position every frame.
no i said when i get a position of game object that enter to collider so if i change the pose of game object that position also  changing even if out of collider range
in general, i need TargetPos get position of gameobject when game object in collider range not update that when i change it

then the trigger is being enterered every frame, or you have other code doing it

I do not fully understand what you mean but i get the position object that enter in trigger and use it.

@BugFinder mean is maybe other object or code do get position/colliding instead of only your player object. I recommend you to check this code in new scene and make sure only 2 objects has Collider in that scene, and let's check when these 2 object colliding, is the trigger enter called once or multiple times.

I'm assuming your question is asking about how TargetPos.position manages to to continuously update every frame, even though the OnTriggerEnter2D callback isn't getting triggered anymore.
That's because your TargetPos variable is a Transform, and Transform is a class.
This means that you're getting a reference to the Transform of the gameObject, not just a copy. If the object moves afterwards, your variable will reflect that change.
To fix this, just change the type of TargetPos from a Transform to a Vector3, just like targetPosTemp and attackDirection:
Vector3 TargetPos;

...

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        TargetPos = collision.gameObject.transform.position;
        attackDirection = TargetPos.position - transform.position;
        targetPosTemp = attackDirection + transform.position;
    }
}


I really appreciate it ...
